# How to implement lockscreen in Xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get access to the device lockscreen in a xamarin forms pcl project.  I have heard about third-party components such as Lockscreen and Passcode but i dont know how to go about it since this is a xamarin forms app not xamarin.android. How would i implement let's say Lockscreen in the android project of my xamarin forms application?

Comment: In PCL you can still implement `Lock Screen` the same way you would in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS.  Simply add the Lock Screen code to the individual Android and iOS projects.  You could also add a Dependency Service to call `Locker.Activate()`.  See the following website for more details: https://components.xamarin.com/view/lock-screen

Comment: How would i implement the dependency service?

Comment: My answer shows how to implement the dependency service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to call `Locker.Activate()` within Xamarin Forms is to use a dependency service.  In your Xamarin.Forms Project, you can add the following code to make the call to the dependency service:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.Android:
        DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().activateLock();
        break;
    case Device.iOS:
        DependencyService.Get<IAppleMethods>().activateLock();
        break;
}
```

Then in your Xamarin.Forms project, create two interfaces: `IAppleMethods` and `IAndroidMethods` that contain the `activateLock()` method.

I'll show the implementation for `IAndroidMethods`:

```
public interface IAndroidMethods
{
    void activateLock();
}
```

Then, in your iOS and Android projects, create classes that implement the interfaces you just created.  This would be your android class:

```
//add appropriate using declarations
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidMethods))]
namespace <YourApp>.Droid
{
    public class AndroidMethods : IAndroidMethods
    {
        public void activateLock()
        {
            Locker.Activate(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context); //Not sure about any other parameters you need to pass in
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out for more info: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: The locker.activate() takes an argument which is the current context or i would say an activity. How would i get the current activity?

Comment: You can try using `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`

Comment: Yes but on entering the right passcode the application  doesn't move to the next screen of the application.